# Convex hull that maximizes number of covered points

Tags: reference-request, optimization, computational-geometry, triangulation, convex-hulls

There is a set $A$ of  2D points, $|A| = m$. My task is to find a subset $B \subset A$, $|B| = n$, such that the convex hull based on $B$ minimizes the number of points from $A$, that do not lie in this convex hull.

Could you please refer to a literature or give me some hints, how to formulate this optimization problem?

Comment: How big are $m$ and $n$?

Comment: approx. m = 500 and n = 10

Answer (score 0):

Here's an integer linear programming formulation with $O(m^3)$ variables and constraints.  Let $\mathcal{T}=\{T \subseteq A: |T|=3\}$ be the set of triangles with vertices in $A$.  For each $i \in A$, let $\mathcal{T}_i \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ be the set of triangles whose convex hull contains $i$.  For $i\in A$, let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether $i\in B$, and let binary decision variable $y_i$ indicate whether point $i$ appears in the convex hull of $B$.  For $T\in\mathcal{T}$, let binary decision variable $z_T$ indicate whether triangle $T$ is selected.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{i\in A} y_i$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{i\in A} x_i &= n \tag 1\\
y_i &\le x_i + \sum_{T\in \mathcal{T}_i} z_T &&\text{for all $i\in A$} \tag 2\\
z_T &\le x_i &&\text{for all $T\in\mathcal{T}$ and $i\in T$} \tag 3
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces $|B|=n$.  Constraint $(2)$ forces a covered point to appear in $B$ or the convex hull of some triangle with vertices in $B$.  Constraint $(3)$ enforces $z_T=1 \implies i\in B$ for all $i\in T$.

If $O(m^3)$ is too big, you can use dynamic column generation to construct useful members of $\mathcal{T}$ as needed.  Alternatively, you can heuristically reduce the number of triangles by taking $\mathcal{T}=\{T \subseteq \text{convexhull}(A): |T|=3\}$.